# Facing some issue in below object prototype question

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the below code -

```
function x(a, b) {
  this.b = b || 'test';
  this.c = false;
}

x.prototype.z = function() {
  if(this.c) {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}

let n = function(a, b, v, d) {
  x.call(this,a, b);
  this.a = a;
  this.v = v;
  this.d = d;
}

n.prototype = Object.create(x.prototype);
let n1 = new n();
```

Which three properties are set for n1? --> i find only b, c are getting set. but it is asking for 3 options

1. c
2. z
3. v
4. d
5. b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what n1 looks like

```
{
  a: undefined,
  b: "test",
  c: false,
  d: undefined,
  v: undefined,
  z: function() {
    if (this.c) {
      console.log('hello')
    }
  }
}
```

z also has a value because with `Object.create(x.prototype)` we copy over the `x.prototype.z` function. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: so the answer should be z, b, c ?

Comment: It's quite the confusing question. Do you need any explanation?

Comment: b, c i knew it.. but i was confused whether z should also be the ans or not?

Comment: This should answer your question